# How do I retrieve and save the data out of a dynamically created control in a dynamically created RadGrid

Tags: c#, telerik-grid, radcombobox, datagridtemplatecolumn

Ok here is the scenario.  I have created a completely data driven Radgrid with only 2 static buttons on the page, Save and Cancel.  The Radgrid is created dynamically, as well as all the data in the grid (from MS SQL).  Here is the tricky part, I have a template column that will contain a control.  The type of control is determined again by the data in SQL.  I.e., data is 6, I need to return a RadTextBox populated with data from SQL, 5 = RadComboBox, also populated...  you get the jist.  I have a total of 50 records, so I have around 50 controls, all populated with data which can change and be saved.  That is the hard part.  I have been stuck for 2 days trying to figure out how to get to the RadGrids cell level, find the control, determine what type of control it is, retrieve the lastest data from that control and save it back out to the Database.  The code works, I just need help finding the controls and saving the data...

I need to hit the Save button, which in turn gets all the data and saves it to db.  I cannot show you all my code because the codebehind is close to 600 lines. but I will demonstrate with one.

I am giving the controls IDs based on a unique value from that row, so ID="c" = x where x is the unique value.

page.aspx

```
<form id="formUnionActivityProtestor" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiCaseId" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hiCaseSequence" runat="server" />
        <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" ScriptMode="Release">
        </telerik:RadScriptManager>
        <div id="headDiv">
                <h2>Blah blah blah</h2>
                <h3>blah zeyblah</h3>

            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnSaveUA" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSaveUA_Click"                    
                Text="Save Union Activity" Skin="Web20" Font-Size="12px" Width="145" Font-Bold="true">
            </telerik:RadButton>

            <telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="btnCancel" OnClientClicking="ReadOnly"
                Text="Cancel Changes" Skin="Web20" Font-Size="12px" Width="145" Font-Bold="true">
            </telerik:RadButton>

        </div>
        <hr />

        <div id="gridContainer" runat="server">
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </div>

</form>
```

page.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    radgrid = new RadGrid();
    radgrid.ID = "radgrid";
    radgrid.PreRender += new EventHandler(radUAGrid_PreRender);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(radgrid);
    this.radgrid.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(this.grid_NeedDataSource);
    radgrid.ItemDataBound += new Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventHandler(this.radgrid_ItemDataBound);            
    radgrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "q_SortValue" };
    radgrid.MasterTableView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    radgrid.MasterTableView.ShowHeader = false;
    radgrid.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;            

    GridBoundColumn boundColumn;

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();            
    boundColumn.ItemStyle.Width = 600;
    boundColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "prompt";
    boundColumn.DataField = "q_Prompt";
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);

    GridTemplateColumn templateColumn = new GridTemplateColumn();
    templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new TemplateColumn("q_QuestionnaireTypeID");            
    //templateColumn.ItemStyle.Width = 0;            
    templateColumn.DataField = "q_QuestionnaireTypeID";
    templateColumn.UniqueName = "q_QuestionnaireTypeID";            
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(templateColumn);

    boundColumn = new GridBoundColumn();            
    boundColumn.Display = false;
    boundColumn.ItemStyle.CssClass = "hidecol";            
    boundColumn.DataField = "t_QuestionnaireTypeDescription";
    radgrid.MasterTableView.Columns.Add(boundColumn);
}

public partial class TemplateColumn : System.Web.UI.Page ,ITemplate  //adding template fields
{
    string fieldName = "";
    int controlTypeID = 0;
    DataTable dt;
    int counter = 1;
    UnionActivity refMgr = new UnionActivity(Global.ICEConnectionString);       

    public TemplateColumn(string fieldName)
    {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }
    public int getQuestionTypeID(int count)
    {
        int k = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                 where (int)dr["q_SortValue"] == count
                 select (Int32)dr["q_QuestionnaireTypeID"]).FirstOrDefault();
        return k;            
    }
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        if (counter == 1)
        {
            dt = UnionActivityDataTable.dt;                
        }
        controlTypeID = getQuestionTypeID(counter);            

        if (controlTypeID == 5)
        {
            int QID = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                        where (int)dr["q_SortValue"] == counter
                        select (int)dr["q_QuestionnaireInstanceID"]).FirstOrDefault();
            int QQID = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                        where (int)dr["q_SortValue"] == counter
                        select (int)dr["q_QuestionnaireInstanceQuestionID"]).FirstOrDefault();
            string answer = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                             where (int)dr["q_SortValue"] == counter
                             select (string)dr["a_Answer"]).FirstOrDefault(); 
            DataTable dt1;
            dt1 = getDropDownList(QID, QQID);
            RadComboBox cb = new RadComboBox();                
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
            {
                RadComboBoxItem item = new RadComboBoxItem();
                item.Text = row["DisplayValue"].ToString();
                item.Value = row["DDID"].ToString();
                if (answer == item.Text)
                {
                    cb.SelectedValue = item.Value;
                }
                cb.Items.Add(item);
                item.DataBind();
            }
            string x = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
                        where (int)dr["q_SortValue"] == counter
                        select Convert.ToString((int)dr["a_QuestionnaireInstanceQuestionID"])).FirstOrDefault();              
            cb.ID = "c" + x; 
            container.Controls.Add(cb);
        }
    }
    DataTable getDropDownList(int QID, int QQID)
    {
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (refMgr)
            {   //retrieving qicr_QuestionnaireInstanceCaseReferenceID
                using (DataTable getDropDownData = refMgr.DynamicDropDownData(QID, QQID))
                {
                    if (getDropDownData != null)
                    {
                        dt2 = getDropDownData;  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return dt2;
    }
}
```

after page load I look at the source and this is the insert for the combobox...

```
<td class="rcbInputCell rcbInputCellLeft" style="width:100%;">
    <input name="radgrid$ctl00$ctl22$c12" type="text" class="rcbInput radPreventDecorate" id="radgrid_ctl00_ctl22_c12_Input" value="Kiosk" readonly="readonly" />
</td>
```

I need to attach a method to the save button, but I dont know the first place to start.  Telerik is good about getting the page built dynamically, but not saving the data back out. (or even finding the controls...)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen something like this done for survey generation. The only difference is that it wasn't using a Grid. Is there a reason why you need to use a grid rather than just dynamically building the controls on the page?

I can suggest a way so that you can easily obtain the values from dynamic controls.

You can introduce an interface that all your survey controls need to implement.

```
interface ISurveyControl 
{
    // expose some common properties
    int QuestionID {get; set;}
    object Value {get; set;}
    // and others as required
}
```

Then create an extension for every type of control that you need in your survey

```
public class SurveyTextBox : RadTextBox, ISurveyControl
{
    public int QuestionID {get; set;}
    public object Value
    {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value.ToString(); }
    }
}

public class SurveyComboBox : RadComboBox, ISurveyControl
{
    public int QuestionID {get; set;}
    public object Value
    {
        get { return SelectedValue; }
        set { SelectedValue = value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Make sure you use these extended controls when building the survey and populate the common properties correctly.

Then all you need is a helper function to find all ISurveyControl controls from a container, regardless of whether it's a grid or a page.

```
List<ISurveyControl > FindSurveyControls(Control container) 
{
    // you can use linq to find all ISurveyControl within the container
    // you may need to make this recursive as well
}
```

You can then iterate through the controls on save, knowing that they hold enough information such as the QuestionID and so on.